# Input the filename in the commandline as an argument in Python

Tags: command-line, scripts, python

I want to do the modification in my code such that I am able to input my file in the same command line where I’m calling python code like:

```
script.py filename
```

Presently my code is:

```
filename = raw_input('Enter a filename: ')
with open(filename) as f:
   next(f)
   for lines in f:
```

Please suggest me how should I proceed with the same.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for.   thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

```py
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]
```

`sys.argv` will be a list of elements in your call.

Answer (score 2):

`sys.argv` is the easiest for a simple use case.

For more advanced uses you could use `argparse`, but I'd prefer [`click` (“Command Line Interface Creation Kit”)](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) which makes creating command line tools with Python really easy:

```py
import click
@click.command()
@click.argument('filename', type=click.Path(exists=True, readable=True), nargs=1)
def main(filename):
    ...

main()
```

using `@click.option()` you can also create custom flags such as `--filename`.

This makes using arguments much easier, as you can define input types that get checked automatically. It also produces nice error messages and with `--help` it prints usage information:

```
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] FILENAME

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
```

---

You will need to install `click`:

```bsh
# Python2:
pip install click

# Python3:
pip3 install click
```

Comment: Got an error: TypeError: main() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filename'. Any clue how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sys` module:

```py
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as filename:
        for line in filename:
               print(line)
```

See also [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1009860/3701431) for usage of `argparse` module to create custom flags such as `-f <filename>`